# Flutter Firebase query - Show set value in Text Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple `FutureBuilder` where where I'm retrieving Firestore data from a Query. I'm returning a QuerySnapshot. In the same query, im updating a "SUM" variable from each document. But How can I use this SUM variable to be displayed inside a Text Widget? since its an async call, the value doesn't update. If i use `setState` inside the firebase query, the value keeps adding without stopping.

I have the Sum  variable initialized in the state:

```
 double sum = 0.0;
```

A typical FutureBuilder calls the query function.
here's my query:

```
Future<QuerySnapshot> getItems() async {

    var snapshot = await  FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Items')
          .where('time', isGreaterThan: _startofDay)
          .where('type', isEqualTo: 'food')
          .orderBy('time', descending: false)
          .get().then((value) {
            value.docs.forEach((element) {
              sum += element['price'];
            });
            return value;
     });
 }
```

I dont want to use another FutureBuilder that runs the same query and return the Sum Value since I want to minimize my firebase document reads.
I just want to display the Sum value in a Text Widget.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<QuerySnapshot> getItems() async {

    var snapshot = await  FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Items')
          .where('time', isGreaterThan: _startofDay)
          .where('type', isEqualTo: 'food')
          .orderBy('time', descending: false)
          .get().then((value) {

            // set sum value as 0 before for each
            setState(() => sum = 0);

            value.docs.forEach((element) {

               // then count sum value again
               setState(() => sum += element['price']);
            });
            return value;
     });
 }
```

Comment: Hi Thanx for the reply. i've returned  a print(sum); before the return statement. But the print value keeps on printing. is that expected?